# Trouble with Adafruit MAX31856 thermocouple sensor

Tags: arduino, sensors, adafruit

I have connected the Adafruit MAX31856 thermocouple sensor to the Arduino and I am now basically trying to run adafruit's code but I get an error that I do not really understand.

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-max31856-thermocouple-amplifier?view=all#wiring-and-test ~ Jump to Library reference and see the complete code provide by Ada

The code lines provided below are the ones displaying error

```
#include <Adafruit_MAX31856.h>
#include <SPI.h>

// Use software SPI: CS, DI, DO, CLK
Adafruit_MAX31856 maxthermo = Adafruit_MAX31856(Α0,Α1,Α2,Α3);

// use hardware SPI, just pass in the CS pin
Adafruit_MAX31856 maxthermo = Adafruit_MAX31856(A0);
```

Instead of pins 10,11,12,13 i am using A0,A1,A2,A3.

I have attached in the pictures below the error messages I get

[Screenshot of Erros 1/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oMDV.png)

[Screenshot of Errors 2/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRQR9.png)

Many thanks for any insight.

Comment: use hardware SPI and wire the sensor to hardware SPI. remove the line for software SPI

Comment: @Juraj I have commented out the last line of the above code and it compiles without a problem. What is the purpose of the line under the second comment if  the pins are declared once? Thanks!

Comment: the Adafruit_MAX31856 can use bit-banged SPI or hardware SPI. if you specify the pins it is bit-banged and can use any pins. then it doesn't use the SPI library and you can remove the include. the hardware SPI is on fixed pins. 11,12,13 on Uno. bit-banged is more work for the MCU